Using class validator forbid same item from being present in 2 different arrays
Hello folks I am working on an University project wherein I need to manage the course taken by the students. The application has a form to add course and delete a course sometimes I observe that students are putting same course in "add" list as well as in "remove" list how do I prevent that from happening
Here is my validation schema
{ IsOptional, IsArray } from "class-validator";

class courseValidate {
    @IsOptional()
    @IsArray()
    addCourses!: string[]


    @IsOptional()
    @IsArray()
    removeCourses!: string[]
}

I tried various custom decorator but they are not working
EDIT: Here's what I've tried
EDIT: I got the solution silly mistake around commonItems.length > 0;
Thanks for the support :-)

import {
  IsArray,
  IsNotEmpty,
  IsOptional,
  IsUUID,
  MaxLength,
  MinLength, Validate,
  ValidationArguments,
  ValidatorConstraint,
  ValidatorConstraintInterface
} from "class-validator";
import { get, intersection, map, trim } from "lodash";

@ValidatorConstraint({name: "uniqueArrays", async: false})
export class UniqueArraysValidation implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
  validate(value: undefined, args: ValidationArguments): boolean {
    let isValid = true
    const remove = map(get(args, 'object.removeCourses', []), e => trim(e));
    const add = map(get(args, 'object.addCourses', []), e => trim(e));
    if(args !== undefined && remove.length && add.length) {
      isValid = this.checkCollision(remove, add)
    }
    return isValid
  }

  checkCollision(list1: string[], list2: string[]): boolean {
    const commonItems = intersection(list1, list2);
    return commonItems.length > 0;
  }

  defaultMessage(args: ValidationArguments) {
    return `The same item cannot be in both 'add' and 'remove' array`;
  }
}

class courseValidate {
    @IsOptional()
    @IsArray()
    addCourses!: string[]


    @IsOptional()
    @IsArray()
    removeCourses!: string[]

    @Validate(UniqueArraysValidation)
    readonly uniqueArrays!: string[];
}


Please show us the custom validator you tried

Shouldn't it be isValid = !this.checkCollision(remove, add)?

I changed commonItems.length > 0; to commonItems.length === 0; for a quick fix, but yes your suggestion is better

If that's all the problem you had, you may want to simply delete the question
